# Поиск элемента в массиве объектов и его сравнение с введённым в input

Tags: javascript, search

Итак, есть массив объектов. Нужно сделать так, что бы все было как в обычном поиске: при вводе в `input` происходит проверка на сходство уже введенных букв и названий. Как это реализовать?

```js
var songs = [{
    artist: {
      name: 'Imagine',
      song: 'Dragons'
    }
  },

  {
    artist: {
      name: 'Five',
      song: 'Finger'
    }
  }
];


document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var val = text.value;

  songs.map(function(item) {
    if (item.artist.name.includes(val)) {
      console.log('вывести все названия, в которых первые 3 буквы совпадают с введенными');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button1">click</button>
```

Comment: Прослушиваешь у input событие onchange и в обработчике события ищешь в массиве сходства, если находишь, делаешь чего тебе нужно.

Comment: Структуру данных я бы тоже упростил, какая-то она слишком сложная здесь.

Comment: @ivan.posokhin В оригинале она выглядит немного по другому, просто здесь всю не записывал.

Answer (score 0):

Привет, просто прицепи addEventListener к элементу input (событие 'input' или событие 'change', в зависимости от цели). Но вообще мне кажется проверку лучше делать с RegEx. И не забудь учесть верхний/нижний регистр. Далее, вместо map я бы использовал forEach. Ну там много еще вещей можно улучшить/переделать).Смотри [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/timatru/dok8beud/)

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', onChange);

function onChange() {
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var val = text.value;

  songs.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.artist.name.includes(val)) {
      console.log(item.artist.name);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: да, все верно, событие input лучше, затупил.

Comment: задача сформулирована расплывчато. Непонятно что все таки нужно